# How to acess the physical address in kernel space

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

How to use the kernel directly modify the data in a memory block address

I want to modify(read and write) the data in a user process virtual address space in kernel space, now i have convert the process virtual address converted to physical address, but how can i modify the data in kernel space.

`linux-3.14 arm64`

in the old version(x86_64) i have used mmap to map / dev / mem, but it's doesn't work in arm64

```
#ifdef MMAP_INVALID_ARGUMENT /*    invalid argument    when mmap   */
    mapStart = (void volatile *)mmap(0, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,     MAP_SHARED | MAP_LOCKED, memfd, 0xF000);

#else
    mapStart = (void volatile *)mmap(0, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_LOCKED, memfd, pa_base);

#endif
```

I find that if the pa_bae is large than 1M, i get `invalid argument`

Comment: There is no need to use physical addresses, why you can't just use copy_to_user API?

Comment: If you are not in current context kmap the needed page and go ahead

Comment: what I want to do is modify the data in the virtual address of the process like gdb do.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to modify the data in userspace address inside the kernel, for that you will need kernel API get_user_pages(). Using get_user_pages() you can read or modify the userspace data in kernel. Here is the description-

> get_user_pages():
>
> Returns number of pages pinned. This may be fewer than the number
>   requested. If nr_pages is 0 or negative, returns 0. If no pages were
>   pinned, returns -errno. Each page returned must be released with a
>   put_page call when it is finished with. vmas will only remain valid
>   while mmap_sem is held. Must be called with mmap_sem held for read or
>   write. get_user_pages walks a process's page tables and takes a
>   reference to each struct page that each user address corresponds to at
>   a given instant. That is, it takes the page that would be accessed if
>   a user thread accesses the given user virtual address at that instant.
>   This does not guarantee that the page exists in the user mappings when
>   get_user_pages returns, and there may even be a completely different
>   page there in some cases (eg. if mmapped pagecache has been
>   invalidated and subsequently re faulted). However it does guarantee
>   that the page won't be freed completely. And mostly callers simply
>   care that the page contains data that was valid *at some point in
>   time*. Typically, an IO or similar operation cannot guarantee anything
>   stronger anyway because locks can't be held over the syscall boundary.
>
> get_user_pages() is typically used for fewer-copy IO operations, to
>   get a handle on the memory by some means other than accesses via the
>   user virtual addresses.

You can refer following links:
[LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/28548/)
[LDD3](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-3)